# C# Windows Service SqlCommand Hangs

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, sqlexception

I have a Windows services running in .NET 4.5. Everything works fine. However, when my service encounters a `SqlException`, it hangs (turns into a zombie).

I have a timer (`System.Timers`) that calls `process`. In `process`, locate `cmd.ExecuteReader()`. If I remove `EXECUTE` permissions from the stored procedure, I receive a `SqlException` (as expected). When this happens, the service simply hangs.

I would have expected one of the `try {} catch` blocks to capture the exception and exit the method gracefully. However, the system appears to hang on this call. I had a number of `Trace` statements in the code. I removed them so it would be easier to read.

```
private void TimerForNotification_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TimerForNotification.Stop();
    int count = new GetSMSNotifications().process();
    TimerForNotification.Start();
}

public int process()
{
    int count = 0;

    // Get the ConnectionStrings collection.
    ConnectionStringSettings connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DE_OLTP"];

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connections.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[get_SMSToSend]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    // increment counter
                    count++;

                    string destinationAddress = Convert.ToString(dr[dr.GetOrdinal("DestinationAddress")]);
                    string alertMessage = Convert.ToString(dr[dr.GetOrdinal("Content")]);

                    // Send out the notification
                    sendPush(destinationAddress, alertMessage);
                }

                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                DELog.Log.Error(se);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DELog.Log.Error(ex);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Interestingly, I created a console app that calls the above method and the `try {} catch` block works as expected.

I don't see any unhandled exceptions in the event log.

Thoughts?

Comment: where exactly does it hang SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader ?

Comment: It hangs on the statement.  In order words, I placed a Trace statement directly before and after the cmd.ExecuteReader() call.  The before statement was written to the log file.  Whereas, the after statement did not.  In the Console App I mentioned, I was able to step into the process method and see the exception happen on this statement.

Comment: On a side note, wrap your `SqlDataReader` and the `while` loop that uses it in a `using` statement - just like you are doing with your `SqlConnection` and the code that uses it.  Your explicit call to `dr.Close()` will never happen if there is a `SqlException` when `cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` is run; and you won't need it after refactoring to employ a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  The reason why it appeared my service was hanging is because I was a missing a reference to `Entity.Framework.dll`.  When the service ran into an exception, the EF dll could not be found.  I use the EF in my logging layer.

I was able to discover this issue by installing my service and then ATTACHing to the run process.

Answer (score 0):

Try these things:

Add trace line to these:

```
TimerForNotification.Stop();

try
{
 int count = new GetSMSNotifications().process();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 // trace line here with ex.ToString().
}

TimerForNotification.Start();
// trace line here stating, i started at DateTime.Now;
```

**Remove execute permissions** and see if the above code generates a trace line.

If it does, then the exception details will show up. (even though your method looks very safe) Fix it accordingly.

If the catch doesn't trace, then you should see trace lines for the post start trace which means the service is working as expected.

Comment: #raja I tried your suggestion but the same behavior occurs.  After looking the problem again, I believe the reason why it appear to be hanging is because the app never returns from .process().  Therefore, the timer does not get restarted.  The SQL Exception is preventing the timer from getting restarted.